# Drupal 7 Views Field Options Alter max_length on First $views->result only and not on any other results

Tags: views, entities

I have a Blog view that displays blog content types and in my view's field settings for my 'body' field I have the rewrite set to trim the body to a specific length (600 words).  This is working well on the display page for the blog.  However, I would like one customization that I can't seem to figure out a work-around for.  I would like the first blog post to display more teaser text than the rest of the blog teasers, but I can't figure out how to manipulate my view object so that the first result has a longer trimmed max length then the rest of the results.  When I dsm my view object I can see results array the first object result is `$view->result[0]` but can't determine any relationship between the result and the altered output.  I can alter the max_length value for the body field in:

```
$view->field['body']->options['alter']['max_length']
```

But this alter's all of the result values and I would only like to alter the first result.

I thought about making another display and limiting it to the most recent blog (the first result) but then I cannot use my exposed filters to filter through the blog posts as the first post will always display at the top of the view.  Any ideas on how I can make this happen?